# Не работает скролл к блоку в google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".nav a").on('click', function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if (href.substring(0, 1) == "#" || (href.substring(0, 2) == "/#" && location.pathname == "/")) {
        $("body").animate({scrollTop: $(href.replace("/", "")).offset().top}, 'slow');
        return false;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл такое решение:

```
$(".nav a").on('click', function() {
var href = $(this).attr("href");
if (href.substring(0, 1) == "#" || (href.substring(0, 2) == "/#" && location.pathname == "/")) {
    $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: $(href.replace("/", "")).offset().top}, 'slow');
    return false;
    }
});
```

Необходимо было указать `$("html, body")`

Comment: `$(href.replace("/", "")).offset().top`? это что такое?))

Comment: Кстати да, `"html,body"` часто вижу при подобных махинациях и это работает ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯